# glfw undeclared identifiers after linking with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, glfw

I am getting 'undeclared identifier' and 'identifier not declared' compiler errors while trying to test whether I've installed GLFW correctly for use with VS 2010.

I downloaded the latest 32 bit binaries from [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/download.html) to be used with Visual Studio 2010.

The glfw3.h and glfw3native.h header file is in the include/gl folder of my Windows SDKs folder and the include folder of my VS 2010 install.

The glfw3.lib and glfw3dll.lib files are in the Windows SDKs lib folder and the VS 2010 install's lib folder.

The glfw3.dll file is in the same folder as the .exe of my VS 2010 project and in my System32 folder.

The duplicate locations exist to determine whether the issue is that my project is not pointing to the correct include, lib directories.

In Linker->Additional Dependencies, I have glfw3.lib, glew32d.lib, opengl32.lib and glu32.lib.  I have tried including glfw3dll.lib separately and in combination with glfw3.lib, same result.

Here is the build log:

```
Build started 7/20/2013 01:00:28.
 1>Project "j:\Users\Guy\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\OpenGL4Test\OpenGL4Test\OpenGL4Test.vcxproj" on node 2 (build target(s)).
 1>InitializeBuildStatus:
     Touching "Debug\OpenGL4Test.unsuccessfulbuild".
   ClCompile:
     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\CL.exe /c /ZI /nologo /W3 /WX- /Od /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _DEBUG /D _CONSOLE /D _UNICODE /D UNICODE /Gm /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc100.pdb" /Gd /TP /analyze- /errorReport:prompt main.cpp
     main.cpp
 1>j:\users\Guy\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\opengl4test\opengl4test\main.cpp(13): error C2065: 'GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR' : undeclared identifier
 1>j:\users\Guy\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\opengl4test\opengl4test\main.cpp(13): error C3861: 'glfwOpenWindowHint': identifier not found
 1>j:\users\Guy\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\opengl4test\opengl4test\main.cpp(14): error C2065: 'GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR' : undeclared identifier
 1>j:\users\Guy\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\opengl4test\opengl4test\main.cpp(14): error C3861: 'glfwOpenWindowHint': identifier not found
 1>j:\users\Guy\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\opengl4test\opengl4test\main.cpp(15): error C3861: 'glfwOpenWindowHint': identifier not found
 1>j:\users\Guy\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\opengl4test\opengl4test\main.cpp(16): error C3861: 'glfwOpenWindowHint': identifier not found
 1>j:\users\Guy\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\opengl4test\opengl4test\main.cpp(19): error C2065: 'GLFW_WINDOW' : undeclared identifier
 1>j:\users\Guy\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\opengl4test\opengl4test\main.cpp(19): error C3861: 'glfwOpenWindow': identifier not found
 1>Done Building Project "j:\Users\Guy\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\OpenGL4Test\OpenGL4Test\OpenGL4Test.vcxproj" (build target(s)) -- FAILED.
Build FAILED.
Time Elapsed 00:00:00.33
```

And the code comes from the an OpenGL 4 tutorial, I changed the glfw header file to reflect the latest download, i.e. from glfw.h to glfw3.h:

```
#include <GL/glew.h> // include GLEW and new version of GL on Windows
#include <GL/glfw3.h> // GLFW helper library
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

int main () {
  // start GL context and O/S window using the GLFW helper library
  glfwInit ();

  // "hint" that the version 4.2 should be run with no back-compat stuff
  int major = 4;
    int minor = 2;
    glfwOpenWindowHint (GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR, major);
    glfwOpenWindowHint (GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR, minor);
    glfwOpenWindowHint (GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwOpenWindowHint (GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

  // open a window of sixe 640x480 with 8bpp and 24 bits for depth sorting
  glfwOpenWindow(640, 480, 8, 8, 8, 8, 24, 8, GLFW_WINDOW);
  // start GLEW extension handler
  glewInit ();

  // get version info
  const GLubyte* renderer = glGetString (GL_RENDERER); // get renderer string
  const GLubyte* version = glGetString (GL_VERSION); // version as a string
  printf("Renderer: %s\n", renderer);
  printf("OpenGL version supported %s\n", version);

    // tell GL to only draw onto a pixel if the shape is closer to the viewer
  glEnable (GL_DEPTH_TEST); // enable depth-testing
  glDepthFunc (GL_LESS); // depth-testing interprets a smaller value as "closer"

  /* OTHER STUFF GOES HERE NEXT */

  // close GL context and any other GLFW resources
  glfwTerminate();
  return 0;
}
```

It seems that most other people have problems linking these libraries, but these are compiler errors?

Comment: One thing is for sure - this has nothing to do with linking. At least some of these identifiers are declared/defined in the `glfw.h` file from 2.7.7 that I have lying around here. You should take a look at the `glfw3.h` file (and maybe the `glfw.h` file if there is one in the 3.x library) to see what's going on with those declarations.

Comment: You are absolutely correct!  I thought something was odd when I searched through the glfw3.h file and did not find those identifiers.  But I was not confident in my knowledge to think that was the problem.  You have to use either the changelog or the link I included in Richard Jones comment to find the correct identifiers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some function names were changed in Version 3 of GLFW, such as glfwOpenWindowHint to glfwWindowHint.

This page gives the version changes, so use CTRL F to find the new function names:

http://www.glfw.org/changelog.html

Also, I found I needed to change `#include <GL/glfw3.h>` to `#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>` as the folder name was changed (check in the GLFW directory to see what yours is).

Hope that helps...

Comment: Nailed it!  I'm also going to include this [link to the Moving from GLFW 2 to 3](http://www.glfw.org/docs/3.0/moving.html) for anyone else who is doing an older OpenGL 4 tutorial that includes version 3. Also, I'm not sure I understand the second part of your comment regarding changing #include to #include?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like `#include "GL/glfw3.h"` now.

If you extract the source file of `glfw` package you will get folder `GLFW` so you need to include it like

```
> #include "GLFW\glfw3.h"
```